# How to query multiple items using Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

After importing the modules:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

and declaring `app` and `db` objects:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I go ahead and create two tables: `User` and `Email`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Email', backref='person', lazy='dynamic')

class Email(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

With `db.relationship` in place I can now link some multiple emails to the same `user`. First I create two email addresses:

```
first_email = Email(email='first@email.com')
second_email = Email(email='second@email.com')
```

Then I am passing these two emails to `User` class at the time it is being created:

```
user = User(name='User Name', addresses = [first_email, second_email])
```

To see which user is linked to which email I can simply use:

```
print first_email.person
print user.addresses.all()
```

Now I want to add another third email to the same `user`. How do I append a new email to the list of the emails that have been already linked to the `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_email = Email(email='new_email@example.com')
user.addresses.append(new_email)
db.session.commit()
```

This will append the email address to the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///inquestion.db' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Email', backref='person', lazy='dynamic')

    def add_email(self, new_email):
        linked_emails = [email.email for email in self.addresses.all()] 
        if not new_email in linked_emails:
            linked_emails.append(new_email)

        self.addresses = [Email.find_or_create(email) for email in linked_emails]



class Email(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    @staticmethod
    def find_or_create(email):
        try:
            return Email.query.filter_by(email=email).one()
        except:
            new_email = Email(email=email)
            db.session.add(new_email)
            db.session.commit()
            return new_email


first_email = Email(email='first@email.com')
second_email = Email(email='second@email.com')

user = User(name='User Name', addresses = [first_email, second_email])

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()


db.session.add(first_email)
db.session.add(second_email)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()

# some extra queries
user.add_email('third@email.com')
print user.addresses.all()

print Email.find_or_create('fourth@email.com')
print Email.query.filter_by(email='fourth@email.com').one().email
print first_email.query.filter_by(email='second@email.com').one()
```